# Failed to connect to Recurly Could not resolve host

Tags: php, wordpress, recurly

I'm currently developing a plugin for wordpress that uses recurly for subscription. I already uploaded it to our site and resume coding there. I'm already done with the checkout page and was in the middle of developing the accounts page when I run into an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Recurly_ConnectionError' with message 'Failed to connect to Recurly (Could not resolve host: xx-my-subdomain-xx.recurly.com)
```

*xx-my-subdomain-xx is the placeholder for the subdomain*

I already increased the connection timeout to 30 but my effort was futile. I tried testing it in my localhost and found out that it was working. I think i has something to do with the cURL but I can't point out what's causing the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Recurly_Client::$subdomain = 'your-subdomain-name'; // i.e devapp,myapp..etc

**You don't need to write whole subdomain URL** you just need to pass your subdomain name which is found in configuration -> site setting (Only the name of the subdomain).

I hope this will solve your issue as I also got the same error after this change its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your subdomain as follows

```
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = "Your RECURLY_SUBDOMAIN";
```

Then add your API key and certificate path as follows

```
Recurly_Client::$apiKey = "Your RECURLY_API_KEY";
```

```
Recurly_Client::$CACertPath = "Your RECURLY_OPENSSL_CertificatePATH";
```

I hope this will work for you.